# How to count the most frequent letter in a string?

Tags: python

```
class MyString:
    def __init__(self, myString):
        self.__myString = myString

    def countWord(self):
         count = len(self.__myString.split())
         return count

    def findMostFrequentChar(self):
        # ?
```

I need to implement `findMostFrequenctChar`. The only hint she gave us was that we needed to make 2 lists. and this is where she lost me.

Here's the code that calls the function:

```
def main():
    aString = MyString("This is a super long long long string. Please help count me")
    print("There are", aString.countWord(), "words in the string.")

    count, letter = aString.findMostFrequentChar()
    print("The most frequent character is", letter, "which appeared", count, "times")

main()
```

Comment: If a `collections.Counter` is out of the question, use a dictionary in order to count each letter. Scrap that two lists idea.

Comment: So, this is homework? This is okay for homework, but keep in mind that good practice would involve cacheing - if your string does not change, it would make sense to pre-compute this value and store it once as an object attribute. Otherwise, dissociate this functionality from the class and define an independent function instead that does the computation for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a dict to store the counting.
But first I want to strip all `spaces` and other symbols then a-z, I also want to count upper & lower-case letters as one and the same.

When the dict is constructed with all my values I use the `max` function.
The `max` takes a iterable, so we pass dict as a "list" of tuples `(key, val)`. We need to tell `max` how to determine what we want to compare, for that we give a lambda function that takes the second element (`val`) in tuple to the `key-arg`.

In return, max will spit out the tuple with the highest `val`.

```
class MyString:

    def __init__(self, myString):
        self.__myString = myString

    def countWord(self):
        count = len(self.__myString.split())
        return count

    def findMostFrequentChar(self):
        counter = {}
        # Instead of performing various modifications on the string
        # one can instead filter all the undesired chars.
        # new_string = self.__myString.replace(' ', '').lower()
        new_string = list(filter(lambda x: 'a' >= x <= 'z', self.__myString.lower()))
        for char in new_string:

            if char in counter:
                counter[char] += 1
            else:
                counter[char] = 1

        key, value = max(counter.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
        return value, key


def main():
    aString = MyString("This is a super long long long string. Please help count me")
    print("There are", aString.countWord(), "words in the string.")

    count, letter = aString.findMostFrequentChar()
    print("The most frequent character is", letter, "which appeared", count, "times")

main()
```

Comment: this code as is doesn't run, how would I get this to run ?

Comment: File "C:/Users/abrooks3/Downloads/assignment9.py", line 31, in main
    count, letter = aString.findMostFrequentChar()
  File "C:/Users/abrooks3/Downloads/assignment9.py", line 21, in findMostFrequentChar
    key, value = max(counter.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1])
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
>>>

Comment: what version of python python do you have?
and you call `iteritems()`

Comment: i have idle 3.6.2

Comment: test using items() instead, sorry for that. iteritems() is removed in python3

Comment: Please have look at the code again..... Made an calculation mistake.... the counter shouldnt be set to 0.... Perhaps 1 is more logical. Bad habit of always thinking 0 as start :)

Answer (score 4):

> The only hint she gave us was that we needed to make 2 lists. and this is where she lost me.

That seems to imply that you cannot use `collections.Counter`,
and probably not even dictionaries.

If we can assume that letters are defined as the English alphabet,
then one list is enough.
In that case, you could create a list of 26 items, all initialized to 0.
Then you could iterate over the characters of the string,
and for each letter of the English alphabet, increment the count of the `n`-th item in the list, where `n` is the index of the letter in the alphabet.

Create a list of 26 zeros:

```
counts = [0] * 26
```

Loop over the characters of the input string `s`:

```
for c in s:
```

Check that the character is a letter:

```
if 'a' <= c.lower() <= 'z'
```

Calculate the 0-based index of the letter in the alphabet and increment the count:

```
index = ord(c.lower()) - ord('a')
counts[index] += 1
```

Once you have the counts,
you can find the index that has the maximum value (left for you as an exercise),
and get the corresponding character with `chr(index + ord('a'))`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sorted`:

```
class String:
    def __init__(self, s):   
       self.s = s
    def findMostFrequentChar(self):
       return sorted([(a, self.s.count(a)) for a in self.s], key=lambda x:x[-1])[-1]
```

Comment: You found the most frequent char. But the counting is missing.

Comment: @DavidBern the OP said that  only `findMostFrequenctChar` had to be implemented.

Comment: and by implementing that uses it likes this `count, letter = aString.findMostFrequentChar()` the test would fail.

Comment: @DavidBern to be safe, I did implement a counting feature.

Answer (score 2):

If you could use `Counter` from `collections` module:

```
from collections import Counter

def findMostFrequentChar(self):
    d = Counter(self.__myString.replace(' ', '').lower())        
    return d.most_common()[0]
```

If `Counter` is out of the question:

```
def findMostFrequentChar(self):
    d = {}

    for ch in self.__myString.replace(' ', '').lower():
        if ch in d:
            d[ch] += 1
        else:
            d[ch] = 1

    most_frequent = max(d, key=d.get)
    return most_frequent, d[most_frequent]
```

Putting it altogether:

```
class MyString:
    def __init__(self, myString):
        self.__myString = myString

    def countWord(self):
         count = len(self.__myString.split())
         return count

    def findMostFrequentChar(self):        
        d = {}

        for ch in self.__myString.replace(' ', '').lower():
            if ch in d:
                d[ch] += 1
            else:
                d[ch] = 1
        most_frequent = max(d, key=d.get)
        return most_frequent, d[most_frequent]


def main():    
    aString = MyString("This is a super long long long string. Please help count me")
    print("There are", aString.countWord(), "words in the string.")

    letter, count = aString.findMostFrequentChar()
    print("The most frequent character is", letter, "which appeared", count, "times")

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I will show you how to get the most frequent letter of a regular string by using a dictionary without any imports. Your job is to adjust your class accordingly.

I assume that if two or more letters share the highest frequency any one of them is a valid result.

```
>>> s = 'aabacbcd'
>>> counts = {}
>>> for c in s:
...     counts[c] = counts.get(c, 0) + 1
... 
>>> counts
{'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1}
>>> max(counts, key=counts.get)
'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

The "two list" part is irritating. One practical tool, however, to count elements of iterables in Python is `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

# ...
    def findMostFrequentChar(self):
        return Counter(self.__myString).most_common()[0][0]
```